# Sandbox Paypal working fine but Live is not

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

i am using this class for a site i am developing for paypal integration for monthly payment

[http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html][1]

How ever its working fine with my sandbox account but when i use it with my paypal live account its not working . i am using an email and ipn_log.txt file for logging the results even if its error but in case of paypal LIVE its not logging any thing or mail . I have enabled IPN on my Paypal account as well .but i cant test my paypal live aaccount due to low funds :( . Here is the code i am changing for Paypal Sandbox and LIVE rest is same for both .  I have also enabled my paypal IPN on my live account.

```
        // For Sandbox
        //$p->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';                     
       //testing paypal url
        $p->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';     




       //In my class changing these lines 
       // open the connection to paypal
       $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30); 

  //open the connection to sandbox
 // $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem - I haven't changed my notify URL for live site.